# Getting NameError: name is not defined. Does it have anything to do with the status of the variables?

Tags: python, function, global-variables, word-frequency

This is my code. I'm new to python and I have defenitely messed up. I'm trying to create a program that calculates the frequency of words in a text file called 'romeoandjuliet.txt'. When I run it, nothing happens and the f1 and f2 files are not created. When type 'listofwords' or 'freq' in the console I get a NameError. I have already taken care of the stopwords situation. I appreciate any help.

```
def main():
    listofwords = formlistofwords('romeoandjuliet.txt')
    
    
    def formlistofwords(filename):
        
        global listofwords
        listofwords = formlistofwords("romeoandjuliet.txt")
        
        infile = open(filename)
        originalline = (infile.readline().lower() for line in infile)
        line = " "
        for ch in originalline:
            if ('a' <= ch <= 'z') or (ch == " "):
                line += ch
                listofwords = line.split()
                listofwords = [i.strip('.,?!:;') for i in listofwords]
                listofwords = [words for words in listofwords if words not in stopwords]
                return listofwords
    
    

    def createfrequencydict(listofwords):
        global freq
                
        freq = [listofwords.count(p) for p in listofwords]
        return dict(list(zip(listofwords, freq)))



    def displaywordcount(listofwords, freq):
        print('romeoandjuliet contains: ', len(listofwords), 'words')
        print('romeoandjuliet contains: ', len(freq), 'different words')
        print()


    def displaymostcommon(freq):
        file1 = open('f1.txt', 'w')
        file2 = open('f2.txt', 'w')
        print('most common words and frequencies are: ')
        listofmostcommonwords = []
        for word in freq.keys():
            if freq[word] >= 30:
                listofmostcommonwords.append((word, freq[word]))
        listofmostcommonwords.sort(key = lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
        for item in listofmostcommonwords:
            print(item[0] + ':', item[1])
        for item in listofmostcommonwords:
            file1.write(str(item[1]) + ',')
            file2.write(str(item[0]) + ',')

        file1.close()
        file2.close()
```

Comment: You put everything in functions but you never run the functions. And it fill never create the variables (" When type 'listofwords' or 'freq' in the console I get a NameError") because everything is local to `main` function

Comment: @h4z3 so I only need to call main() at the end?

Comment: Yes and no. Yes - it will run main. No - 1. you don't do anything with `listofwords` (you don't run either of the display functions, which I assume you want), 2. `formlistofwords` is recursive without stop, it will break 3. even when you fix infinite recursion, you return from that function in the loop, so you'll only process one line at most

Comment: @h4z3 so what do I need to do. I'm kind of lost. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: 1. You need to run main, as you said 2. You need to re-think the rest of your code because as I said, it has many flaws, including breaking it.

Answer (score 0):

I studied your code. I noticed following points:

1. You need to call each function in order to execute
2. You have some global variables such as `listofwords`,`freq`. Declare them and assign `None` to them. Then call the functions at then end passing these variable. This way code is working
3. Following return statement

   `return dict(list(zip(listofwords, freq)))`

Here the return statement is not returning dictionary. It is returning list. Instead of this, first try this using for loop. Here is the code that worked for me

```
def createfrequencydict(listofword):
    global freq
    freq = [listofwords.count(p) for p in listofwords]
    #print(dict(list(zip(listofwords, freq))))
    for key in listofwords:
        for value in freq:
            res[key] = value
            freq.remove(value)
            break  
    return res
```